# Send and receive json obj in Android

Tags: java, android, json, http, networking

I am currently working with an app that can access an online game to acquire information of my account. I need to use JSON to communicate with the server. I used the following code to try to communicate with the server, but there are no responds from the server. I also noticed that the httpclient and some other popular class were deprecated and I can't find some proper tutorial to teach me on this topic. Any help is appreciated.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="deardanielxd.travain2.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Username : "
    android:id="@+id/Username_Lbl"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:editable="true"
    android:minHeight="20dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Username_Field"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/Username_Field"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Password_Lbl" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height = "40dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:id="@+id/Username_Field"
    android:editable="true"
    android:contextClickable="true"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Load_Btn"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Password_Lbl" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Password : "
    android:id="@+id/Password_Lbl"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Username_Lbl"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:minHeight="20dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Password_Field" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:id="@+id/Password_Field"
    android:password="true"
    android:editable="true"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:contextClickable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Username_Field"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Username_Field" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Load"
    android:id="@+id/Load_Btn"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Password_Field" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/Load_Btn"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Password_Lbl" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/SysMsg"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:text="System : "
    android:textColor="#FF0000" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/SysMsg"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/OutPut"
        android:enabled="true" />
</ScrollView>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package deardanielxd.travain2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner spinner;
    EditText Username, Password;
    Button Load_Btn;
    TextView Main_Output;
    TextView Sys_Output;
    String server = "";
    boolean debug = true;
    PlayerInfo curr = new PlayerInfo();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SetupGadget();
        attachListener();

    }

    private void SetupGadget() {
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        Username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Username_Field);
        Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Password_Field);
        Load_Btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Load_Btn);
        Main_Output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.OutPut);
        Sys_Output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SysMsg);

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,Constants.Servers);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void attachListener() {
        Load_Btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (debug) {
                    MainOutput( "Username : " + Username.getText());
                    MainOutput( "Password : " + Password.getText());
                    MainOutput( "Server : " + server);
                    MainOutput( "Internet Connection : " + (InternetAccess()?"Yes":"No"));
                    MainOutput( "" );
                }

                new test(MainActivity.this).execute();

            }
        });

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                server = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void SystemOutput(String output) {
        Sys_Output.setText("System : " + output);
    }

    public void MainOutput(String output) {
        Main_Output.append("\n" + output);
    }

    private boolean InternetAccess() {
        ConnectivityManager cm =
                (ConnectivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetwork != null &&
                activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

    }

    public class test extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>

    {
        private MainActivity MA;

        test(MainActivity ma) {
            MA = ma;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... n) {

            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://"+MA.server+"/api/external.php");
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Host", "android.schoolportal.gr");
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
                urlConnection.connect();

                OutputStream printout = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream ());
                printout.write(URLEncoder.encode(this.getObj().toString(),"UTF-8").getBytes());
                printout.flush ();
                printout.close ();

                try {
                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder(in.available());
                    String line;
                    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                        total.append(line).append('\n');
                    }
                    MA.MainOutput(total.toString());
                    MA.MainOutput("End of Doc");
                } finally {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                    return null;
                }
            } catch (java.net.MalformedURLException e) {

            } catch (java.io.IOException e) {

            };
            return null;

        }

        private JSONObject getObj() {

            JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();
            try {
                jobj.put("email","funckybuggy@gmail.com");
                jobj.put("siteName","EasyTravian");
                jobj.put("sitUrl","testing.com");
                jobj.put("public",false);
            } catch (org.json.JSONException e) {

            }
            return jobj;

        }

    }

    public PlayerInfo getCurrentPlayerInfo() {
        return this.curr;
    }

    public void UpdateCurr() {
        this.curr.Username = this.Username.getText().toString();
        this.curr.Password = this.Password.getText().toString();
        this.curr.Server = this.server;
    }

    }
```

Constants.java

```
public class Constants {
public static final String[] Servers = {
    "ts1.travian.hk",
    "ts2.travian.hk",
    "ts20.travian.hk",
    "tx3.travian.hk",
    "ts4.travian.hk",
    "ts19.travian.hk",
    "ts3.travian.hk",
    "ts6.travian.hk",
    "ts5.travian.hk"
};

}
```

Comment: Mate look into Volley, will make your life easier here

Comment: Try [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use Volley Library for it.
It's very good for the Rest API's.

And managing server calls is simple with it.

Add the library by compiling

```
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
```

then make a Singleton class to handle all the volley requests.

Volley provides JsonArrayRequest and JsonObjectRequest which are very helpful during network calls.

Here is volley singleton class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application
{

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private static MyApplication mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance()
    {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getReqQueue()
    {
        if (mRequestQueue == null)
        {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToReqQueue(Request<T> req, String tag)
    {

        getReqQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToReqQueue(Request<T> req)
    {

        getReqQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingReq(Object tag)
    {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

Add this to your application tag in manifest

```
<application
android:name="MyApplication">
```

This is a sample JsonObjectRequest

```
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest("requestMethod","url","input_data",
                        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
                            {
                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                            {
                            }
                        });
                MyApplication.getInstance().addToReqQueue(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should encode the body of the message.
The reason it is called "URLEncoder" is because it is used to encode a URL but this is the body of your message.

Also, the internal try block you have is redundant and also you should change the request method to GET in the middle of the request.

There's no need to flush the bytes.

Remember that with a POST request, nothing is sent until you read the response using your InputStream.